# Gradle import error in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I've been used to Maven and now I'm trying to import a Gradle based project in IntelliJ:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1'
        compile 'com.google.guava:guava:r09'
        compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.17.1'
        compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.17.1'
        compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.17.1'
        compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.17.1'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.1'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.2.1'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.1'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.1'
        compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'

        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    }

    group = 'com.kinvey'
    version = '0.1.0'

    // Checkstyle
    apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
    checkstyle {
        ignoreFailures = true
        configFile = rootProject.file('codequality/checkstyle.xml')
    }

    // FindBugs
    apply plugin: 'findbugs'
    findbugs {
        ignoreFailures = true
    }

    // PMD
    apply plugin: 'pmd'
    //tasks.withType(Pmd) { reports.html.enabled true }

//    apply plugin: 'cobertura'
//    cobertura {
//        sourceDirs = sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
//        format = 'html'
//        includes = ['**/*.java', '**/*.groovy']
//        excludes = []
//    }

}
```

Here's how I import it and the error:

[image]

[image]

What can be wrong in the way I import the project?

Comment: The error I see suggests that you are configuring the eclipse plugin, but I don't see any eclipse configuration in your build script. If that exists somewhere, can you post it? Also, note that you only need to apply the idea plugin once at the top, then make sure you run `gradle idea` and just "Open" the project, not create new or import.

Comment: 1. Try to remove the "apply plugin: 'eclipse'" line.
2. Try different versions of Gradle. E.g. 3.0 may work while 3.1 wouldn't. Use https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html  to manipulate Gradle versions.
3. Don't forget to file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com